# Oracle SQL - ORA-00936 on DATE()

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-char, ora-00936

so for some reason oracle sql doesn't like this:

```
select count(DEPARTURE_DATE) as DEPARTURES_THIS_MONTH
 from DEPARTURE_DATES
 where to_char(DEPARTURE_DATES.DEPARTURE_DATE, 'MMYYYY') = to_char(date('2014-10-11 00:00:00'), 'MMYYYY')
```

Can anyone see what the problem with this is?
I've spent 30 minutes looking at this and can't figure out what its on about...

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date` isn't a function in Oracle, so `to_char(date('2014-10-11 00:00:00'), 'MMYYYY')` means nothing.

However, there is a [`to_date` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) which works like the inverse of `to_char`.

Instead of `date('2014-10-11 00:00:00')`, something like this should work:

```
TO_DATE('2014-10-11 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Looks like he might have been using this as a reference (1st google result for 'oracle date()') which despite the URL is actually a mysql reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Thanks man! - It works.
I have guided by using this link as well https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @Bart: that link is the **MySQL** manual, not the Oracle DBMS manual.

Comment: I actually just submitted feedback to Google about this because the word "Oracle" isn't even mentioned once in the entire text of that page which is the first result when searching "Oracle date()" so it's easy to see how people can get confused

Answer (score 1):

There is no `date` function in Oracle although there is a `to_date()`

You probably want this:

```
select count(DEPARTURE_DATE) as DEPARTURES_THIS_MONTH
 from DEPARTURE_DATES
 where to_char(DEPARTURE_DATES.DEPARTURE_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY') = '11102014';
```

There is no point in converting a String to Date and then back to String. 'DD' part in the format mask was missed, you probably want that too.